# Chromium "Always on Visible Workspace"

Tags: xfce, chromium, workspaces

I am on Xfce4 and use several wokrspaces as well as two monitors. And I often use "Always on Visible Workspace" option from window menu summoned from titlebar. But Chromium does not have a title bar how can I call this option for its windows?

Answer (score 5):

Right-clicking the top bar a drop-down menu pops up, which contains an "Use system title bar and borders" entry;

Click on it in order to enable the system title bar, which when right-clicked will show the workspace-related options.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 22.04, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

There is option in chromium to "allow window to look like other windows".
I forget the exact words.
Please look for it.